# Listening to variable change in a service in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

What is the best way to listen to a variable change in Anuglar2 service. And on this change the component updates itself.

Comment: Use an Observable.

Comment: To be more exact, use `Subject` to store variable's value. `Subject` is an `Observable` anyway, so you can `subscribe` to it in the component to update your view when needed.

Comment: See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Does this answer your question? [listen to service variable change from component angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259419/listen-to-service-variable-change-from-component-angular)