# listen to service variable change from component angular

Tags: angular, variables, service, components

I have service with variable and method that brings data to that variable

```
export class UserService {
  userDetails;
  getUserProfile(){
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI+'/UserProfile').subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.userDetails=res;
      //  console.log(res);
      },
      err=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

now I want to check from component when the variable changes and read it. How can I do that ?

**UPDATE.**

```
export class UserService {
  userDetails;

  getUserProfile(){
  this.http.get(this.BaseURI+'/UserProfile').subscribe(
    res=>{
      this.userDetails=res;
    },
    err=>{
      console.log(err);
    }
  )
  }
```

In component I have this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.userDetails.subscribe((userDetails) =>this.userDetails=userDetails)
  }
```

Now When I run the app I get error in component:

> AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe'
>   of undefined

Comment: create a Subject and add value to it when `userDetails` change, subscribe to the Subject in the component?

Comment: can u write that like answer ?I'm novice in angular

Comment: Yes, so before I do that where do you eventually need `userDetails`? in your component? or in the service?

Comment: userDetails are already declared in the service. And service has method to get new data into that variable. What I need is to listen from component to that variable change. and if it changes grab the data to component. So In component I want to have the same userDetails variable updated form service variable on change event.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you basically need the data in the component when your get request is completed.

Solution 1: Consider making `userDetails` as an Observable, . This way you could listen to it when the value in it changes

```
export class UserService {

    private _userDetails: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();    // consider putting the actual type of the data you will receive
    public userDetailsObs = this._userDetails.asObservable();
    getUserProfile(){
        return this.http.get(this.BaseURI+'/UserProfile').subscribe(
          res=>{
            this._userDetails.next(res)
          //  console.log(res);
          },
          err=>{
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
    }
}
```

Inside your component(s)

```
constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.userDetailsObs.subscribe((userDetails) => {
        console.log(userDetails)
    })
}
```

---

Solution 2. Consider just returning the HTTP observable itself.

```
getUserProfile(){
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI+'/UserProfile');
}
```

Inside your component(s)

```
constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.getUserProfile.subscribe((userDetails) => {
        console.log(userDetails)
    })
}
```

Comment: this happens only when ngOnInit() problem is that component is already rendered.

Comment: I've tested it and it only works from the beginning when all components are rendered. but I want it to work also after that when I call that service

Comment: @David: Its a `subscription` you have created it when you initialized the component and that subscription will keep listening to changes in `userDetails` throughout until the subscription is killed.

Comment: I'm trying to do it somehow my way, please read the question Update. But I get error. I know that I am doing something wrong, can you check what exactly ?

Comment: @David: The error says it correct, the service class variable `userDetails` doesn't have a value in begining (also `subscription()` won't exist on a normal data type). Did you not follow my answer? I have initialized userDetails as a Subject..

Comment: @David how do you invoke the "HTTP get" request? is it some button click? I mean when do you call getUserProfile()?

Comment: I call HTTP request get after I login to site. And of course this component inits before this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190374/discussion-between-xyz-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

Have your service just have this:

```
export class UserService {
  getUserProfile(){
   return this.http.get(this.BaseURI+'/UserProfile');
 );
}
```

Then in your component, you subscribe to it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ServiceName} from '../servicename.service';

export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private serviceName:ServiceName) { }
    public userDetails={};
    ngOnInit() {
        this.serviceName.getUserProfile().subscribe({
            next: res=> {this.userDetails=res}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this happens only when ngOnInit() problem is that component is already rendered.

Comment: I've tested it and it only works from the beginning when all components are rendered. but I want it to work also after that when I call that service